# video streaming is very slow in java spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, video-streaming

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/video/{clientID}/{fileName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getClientVideo(@PathVariable(value = "clientID") Integer clientID, @PathVariable(value = "fileName") final String fileName) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    String absolutePath = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
    File file = new File(Paths.get(absolutePath).getParent() + "/" + clientID);
    if (null != file) {
        FilenameFilter beginswithm = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File directory, String filename) {
                return filename.contains("ClientVideo_"+fileName);
            }
        };
        File[] files = file.listFiles(beginswithm);
        if (null != files && files.length > 0) {
            Resource resource = null;
            for (final File f : files) {
                headers.set("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + f.getName());

                StreamingResponseBody responseBody = new StreamingResponseBody() {
                    @Override
                    public void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
                        out.write(Files.readAllBytes(f.toPath()));
                        out.flush();
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).body(responseBody); //(responseBody, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        }
    }
    RecruiterResponseBean resBean = new RecruiterResponseBean();
    resBean.setStatusMessage("Video is not present : " + Constants.FAILED);
    resBean.setStatusCode(Constants.FAILED_CODE);
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

video streaming is working but it is very slow. how to increase the efficiency? 
There is no problem with internet it is 10mbps. i am using tomcat 7 and Spring MVC[4.2.4]. should I change the tomcat capacity or how it can be solve? i am not getting in google.

Comment: ou aren't streaming anything. You are first loading everything and then stream it instead of stream what you read in chunks. Regardless of your container this will be slow.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replay. Can you please suggest me to solve this? how can i read in chunks

Comment: Don't use `Files.readAllBytes()` that reads the whole file in-memory before streaming it, use something like `Files.copy(f.toPath(), out)`. Also you cannot send multiple files like that you can only return a single file, not multiple. If there are multiple files and you want to send them you would need to create a `zip` and stream that.

Comment: Thank you Deinum. I will try it now